# No puedo resolver un error en un pequeño programa en Python 3 con tkinter y sqlite3

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

soy un principiante en programación, estoy aprendiendo Python de forma autodidacta. Viendo un tutorial donde explican como utilizar tkinter y sqlite3, me puse a seguir los pasos, pero se me presenta un error (en realidad varios, algunos los pude solucionar, pero este no), les copio el código:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    
    from tkinter import ttk
    
    import sqlite3
    
    class Product:
            
        def _init_(self, window):
            self.wind = window
            self.wind.title('Products Application')
        
    if _name_ == '_main_':
        window = Tk()
        application = Product(window)
        window.mainloop()
```

y el error es este:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 13, in <module>
    if _name_ == '_main_':
NameError: name '_name_' is not defined
```

Yo se que es algo muy tonto para ustedes pero para mi es importante tratar de resolverlo, para poder seguir adelante. No me es tan fácil aprender ya que tengo una edad donde la mayoría no estaría estudiando esto.

Desde ya les agrezco cualquier ayuda y sino sabre entender.

Disculpen la molestia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando un solo guión bajo de cada lado en el método constructor.

Cambia de:

```
def _init_
```

A:

```
def __init__
```

Lo mismo con *name*

Comment: gracias Adrian, se solucionó en parte, ahora me pone: Undefined variable Tk.

Comment: Solucionado, modifiqué window = TK() por window = tk.Tk() y quedo. Muy agradecido.

Comment: Hola, marcelosss7. Me alegro de que lo hayas podido solucionar. Saludos.